# translate Expokit into C

Tags: c, fortran, fortran77, fortran-iso-c-binding

I would like to use 'expokit' package written in fortran77 in C language. I do have installed on my linux system f2c and I translated zhpadm.f files into zhpadm.c. What next should I do to exponentiate matrix in C. What files should I include in the main C program?

How do I pass argument to the function zhpadm() in C? My problem is with 2d arrays. I don't know how to pass these, and I don't know how to pass complex numbers. For real 1d arrays it works.

I am using gfortran and gcc.

Comment: What is the precise reason for wanting to have this routine in C? Be aware that f2c generates C code which is hard to read and is generally considered to be unmaintainable. It also depends on a special library. Consider compiling the package with gfortran and calling the routines you want from C using the standard facilites of Fortran's C interop, using a wrapper function which makes the interfacing easier.

Comment: I wanted to call fortran subroutines from C, but I have problems with 2d arrays. I don't know how to pass them and with complex numbers. For real 1d arrays it works. I haven't tried yet with 1d complex arrays. I am using complex.h in C

Comment: Calling the Fortran version should be A LOT easier, than doing a good translation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass data into a multi-dimensional array from C to Fortran, you have to understand the lay-out of Fortran arrays.

Fortran arrays consist of a sequence of storage locations.  Assume you have a Fortran subroutine

```
   subroutine foo(a,n,m)
   real, intent(inout) :: a(n,m)
```

This gives you an N*M array.  By default, Fortran array indices start from one, so `A(1,1)` refers to the first array element at the first storage location.  The elements then are, in sequence, A(1,1), A(2,1), A(3,1), ..., A (N-1,1), A(N,1), A(1,2), A(2,2), ... until A(N,M).

Assume that, on the C side, you have a pointer pointing to the first element.  Let us assume this pointer is `ap`.

Then, `ap[0]` would refer to `A(1,1)`, `ap[1]` to `A(2,1)` etc.  In general, if you want to refer to `A(I,J)` on the Fortran side, you have to refer to `ap[(i-1)+n*(j-1)]` on the C side.  Of course, on the C side, it would be more ideomatic to use zero-based access in C.

So, if you want to construct an array for Fortran which looks like

```
A = | 1 4 |
    | 2 5 |
    | 3 6 |
```

you could use the following C code:

```
   int n=3, m=2;
   int count = 1,
   for (i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
        for (j=0; j<m; j++)
         {
           ap[i+n*j] = count;
           count ++;
         }
     }
```

Complex numbers are easy in Fortran - the real and imaginary part inhabit two consecutive storage locations.  You are allowed to use this in your program.  COMPLEX*16 is an old, non-standard form for double precision complex.

It makes sense to write a wrapper function around zhpadm.f. Make that function bind(C) and have it reserve the required workspace for zhpadm.

For further hints, read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info .